# Copy and paste values in predetermined cells

Tags: excel, vba

All what the code does is to copy three values and paste it into a new sheet

The question is whether there is a shorter way in order to have the code more compact?

A loop would an option. However, the last lines to be copied and paste do not have a difference of 2. That is why i thought that a loop with "step 2" wouldnt yield the desired result.

```
   Dim wb As Workbook, wq As Object
   Dim ws As Worksheet, datDatum
   Dim cell As Range

   Set wb = Workbooks.Add
   Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Table")
    ws.Select

   Workbooks("Eigene Fundingspreads.xlsm").Sheets("Plain 
   Vanilla").Range("C29").Copy
   ws.Range("J106").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues  

   Workbooks("Eigene Fundingspreads.xlsm").Sheets("Plain 
   Vanilla").Range("C31").Copy
   ws.Range("L106").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

  Workbooks("Eigene Fundingspreads.xlsm").Sheets("Plain 
  Vanilla").Range("C33").Copy
  ws.Range("N106").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

  Workbooks("Eigene Fundingspreads.xlsm").Sheets("Plain 
  Vanilla").Range("C36").Copy
  ws.Range("Q106").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Second Round of copying

```
  Workbooks("Eigene Fundingspreads.xlsm").Sheets("Plain 
  Vanilla").Range("L29").Copy
  ws.Range("J113").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

 Workbooks("Eigene Fundingspreads.xlsm").Sheets("Plain 
 Vanilla").Range("L31").Copy
 ws.Range("L113").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

 Workbooks("Eigene Fundingspreads.xlsm").Sheets("Plain 
 Vanilla").Range("L33").Copy
 ws.Range("N113").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

 Workbooks("Eigene Fundingspreads.xlsm").Sheets("Plain 
 Vanilla").Range("L36").Copy
 ws.Range("Q113").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to avoid copying. Much faster is assigning value of a source cell to a target cell. Especially, if all you need is the value of a cell. You can do it this way:

```
Dim wbEigene As Workbook
Set wbEigene = Workbooks("Eigene Fundingspreads.xlsm")
Dim wsPlainVanilla as Worksheet
Set wsPlainVanilla = wbEigene.Worksheets("Plain Vanilla")

'this way is more efficient than copying:
ws.Range("J106").Value = wsEigene.Range("C29").Value
```

Dim all your sheets and workbooks and use these variables to make your code more readable and easy to maintain.

Comment: that code doesnt work much. The values are supposed to be pasted into an other sheets named "ws".Moreover, I have more cells to copy in order to paste it into another sheet and the question is whether there is a more compact way to code it.Otherwise i would have about 10 line of code just to copy ten cells

Comment: My answer was a general guideline. If you want a more percise solution to your particular problem then post complete code. If you have more cells to copy then a loop should be a way to go.

Please edit your question with complete code.

Comment: Thank you. I just did. This works but it pretty cumbersome and long. I dont know if the loop command would have the desired effect.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Your copying range do not have any pattern so loop might not be the best way. I have changed copying to assigning values as it is much better option.

Comment: I see, this line "ws.Range("J106").Value = wsEigene.Range("C29").Value" shall be adjusted furhter to the other cells to be copied from?

Comment: Yes - this is a guideline, a general rule - copying is not the best way to move data. Just try it and if it is faster and easier to ready then modify the rest of your code :)

Answer (score 1):

The final answer would be this:

```
ws.Range("J106").Value = wsEigene.Range("C29").Value

ws.Range("L106").Value = wsEigene.Range("C31").Value

ws.Range("J106").Value = wsEigene.Range("C29").Value

ws.Range("N106").Value = wsEigene.Range("C33").Value
```